# ng-class ($valid) within ng-repeat does not work on dynamically loaded forms via ng-include

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class, angularjs-ng-include

$valid does not work on dynamically loaded forms via ng-include or I do a mistake (I can't change the style of the Box on form validation):

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WA5ohXoMrb5QcUdl0uwe?p=preview

If the text input field is filled, the color should be changed from black to green.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

  <div class="menu-mantle">
  <div ng-repeat="item in my.forms" class="menu-box">
      <div class="auWizard-default" ng-class="{
       'auWizard-valid': {{item.form_name}}.$valid,
       'auWizard-invalid': {{item.form_name}}.$invalid}">
      </div>
      <div class="menu-default" ng-click="my.getForm(item.form_name)">
        {{item.form_name}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>Forms will be included below:</h4>
<div class="form-area">
  <h5>{{my.src}}</h5>
  <ng-include src="my.src">
  </ng-include>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracking current Form name in controller by

```
$scope.my.getForm= function (form) {
        $scope.currentform=form;
        $scope.my.src=form+".html";
      }
```

I moved `<form>` tag from individual file to index file and it is working now.

```
     <form name={{currentform}}>
       <ng-include src="my.src">
      </ng-include>
     </form>
```

[Working plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JNeTY90pL3YTFJo7v75?p=preview)

Comment: thank you but I now, that is working. The complete form must be (with form tags) on external files. I am trying to catch the loading time of form1, form2 etc.

Comment: @Vienna can you elaborate more .I am not getting your loading time  thing

Comment: while $valid trys to execute the validation there is no form1 in the page, it will be loaded afterwards, therefore $valid has no effect on it

Comment: But it is a solution, maybe we do that in this manner, thank you!

Comment: Recently I come across this https://github.com/Selmanh/angularjs-form-builder . you can have look for custom form builder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

  <div class="menu-mantle">
  <div ng-repeat="item in my.forms" class="menu-box">
      <div class="auWizard-default" ng-class="{
       'auWizard-valid': isFormValid(item.form_name),
       'auWizard-invalid': !isFormValid(item.form_name)}">
      </div>
      <div class="menu-default" ng-click="my.getForm(item.form_name)">
        {{item.form_name}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>Forms will be included below:</h4>
<div class="form-area">
  <h5>{{my.src}}</h5>
  <ng-include src="my.src">
  </ng-include>
</div>
</body>
```

**In your controller**

```
$scope.isFormValid = function(formName){
 var formSelector = 'form[name='+formName+']';
 var formEle = $(formSelector);
 var formScope = angular.element(formEle).scope();
 if(formScope){
    return formScope[formName].$valid;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same effect see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/SGgO95lCZahCo4mbJHCb?p=preview  . Some how there is no connection between the form-names..

Comment: @Vienna Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: does stil not work, form1 is not existing at the time of validation, unfortunately..